# PHP GD create image wrong

Tags: php, gd

i am trying to create image  with PHP and GD library

when i wrote this code no error found

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(120,120) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
for ($i =0; $i<120; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j<120; $j++) {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($im,rand(0,255),rand(0,255),rand(0,255)); 
               imagesetpixel($im, $i,$j,$color);              
}
}
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im2);
?>
```

but i need to set random color for each different pixel ,but i dont know why loop stop in 15 when i set width and height for 120px

what is the problem?

Comment: After 15 pixels successfully randomized, the script stops? without an error?

Comment: i know its no error but i need random color for each pixel for all 12X120 pixel

Comment: Each time i run your script. I get different colors. What do you expect to print ?

Comment: http://im35.gulfup.com/4At9d.png that what i get when i run code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because at some point `imagecolorallocate` will return false or another negative value.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php

> **Warning** This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

You actually try to create the same color for the image over and over again. So simply consider that you may already have allocated / created the random color in your loop :

```
for ($i=0; $i<120; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j<120; $j++) {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($im, rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255)); 
        if ($color) {
            imagesetpixel($im, $i, $j, $color);
        } else {
            imagesetpixel($im, $i, $j, rand(0, 255));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]